# Как показывать карту при клике на выделенный адрес в тексте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Хочу добавить карту во всплывающее окно, которое будет отображаться при клике на определенный адрес в тексте. Например, Яндекс.Почта умеет выделять адреса. 
Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JS API Яндекс.Карт есть **Геоссылка** - модуль Geolink, который позволяет выделить адрес, координаты или название организации в тексте страницы. При клике будет открыта статическая карта с возможностью перейти на Яндекс.Карты.

Как добавить:

Загрузить на страницу код API с модулем Geolink. Для этого нужно в заголовок HTML-страницы вставить строку:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=Geolink"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Обернуть нужный текст в HTML-элемент с CSS-классом «ymaps-geolink»:

```
<span class="ymaps-geolink"> Москва, ул. Крылатские холмы, 26 </span>
```

---

[Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geolink-docpage/?from=SO)   |   [Примеры](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolink?from=SO)

Comment: допустим....а как тогда быть если это не дом а просто улица? сквер к примеру, фонтан?

Comment: @DenisRodionov вы можете также указать адрес с точностью до улицы. Фонтан тоже можно указать, но тут весь вопрос, найдётся ли он на Яндекс.Картах по запросу, обернутому в ссылку.

Comment: Я еще раз говорю. Я не говорю про дом, у которого есть улица и номер дома я говорю про объекты на улицы не имеющие ну улицу можно указать... но фонтан...у него чтоб точно указать это только через географич. координаты...надеюсь сейчас то поняли про что имею ввиду...

Comment: @DenisRodionov давайте без грубости. Тоже ещё раз повторюсь, обернуть в Геоссылку можно _любой_ текст, но результат будет только, если по этому запросу можно найти объект на картах Яндекса. 
Раз словами вы не понимаете, [вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/760594je/)

Comment: @Reni как задать направление появления мини-окна с картой? сейчас она в footer'е и улетает вниз, сдвигая весь стиль подвала..
[![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9lKP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9lKP.jpg)

Comment: направление задать нельзя